# udev device group permissions not behaving as expected

Tags: udev

I have a USB device with a serial interface that masquerades as a USB modem. It gets assigned to `/dev/ttyACM0`, and `udev` rules set the group and mode as noted:

```
amm@AMM:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 
crw-rw----+ 1 root plugdev 166, 0 May 12 20:34 /dev/ttyACM0
```

My user is in the appropriate group:

```
amm@AMM:~$ groups
amm sudo plugdev
```

Yet this user cannot connect to the device without using `sudo`

```
amm@AMM:~$ screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200
[screen is terminating]
amm@AMM:~$ sudo !!
sudo screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200
[detached from 21073.pts-0.AMM]
```

What doesn't this user have access? This is arm64 linux running on (very) custom hardware, but I can connect with root access, so clearly the hardware works.

For reference, here's the `udevadm test` output:

```
amm@AMM:~$ sudo /sbin/udevadm test /devices/soc/6a00000.ssusb/6a00000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.1/tty/ttyACM0
calling: test
version 232
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          232
file size:         8669202 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1850786 bytes
nodes              6818336 bytes
Load module index
Found container virtualization none
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/usr/lib/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/39-usbmuxd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-block.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-crda.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-fuse.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-openocd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/65-libwacom.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-debian-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-mouse.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-touchpad.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-special-net-names.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-debian-compat.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-ifupdown.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-libinput-device-groups.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-regulatory.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-libinput-model-quirks.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-csr.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-hid.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-wup.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-spidev-open.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 196608 bytes tokens (16384 * 12 bytes), 22832 bytes strings
11664 strings (98682 bytes), 9646 de-duplicated (77869 bytes), 2019 trie nodes used
GROUP 20 /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:26
GROUP 46 /lib/udev/rules.d/60-openocd.rules:132
MODE 0660 /lib/udev/rules.d/60-openocd.rules:132
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules:8
/sys/devices/soc/6a00000.ssusb/6a00000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.1: if_class 2 protocol 0
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules:8
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules:15
LINK 'serial/by-path/platform-xhci-hcd.0.auto-usb-0:1.5:1.1' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules:16
IMPORT builtin skip 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules:19
LINK 'serial/by-id/usb-ARM_DAPLink_CMSIS-DAP_0311000032254e4500518006aebb0014bbf1000097969900-if01' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules:23
RUN 'uaccess' /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules:15
handling device node '/dev/ttyACM0', devnum=c166:0, mode=0660, uid=0, gid=46
preserve permissions /dev/ttyACM0, 020660, uid=0, gid=46
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/166:0' to '../ttyACM0'
found 'c166:0' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2fserial\x2fby-id\x2fusb-ARM_DAPLink_CMSIS-DAP_0311000032254e4500518006aebb0014bbf1000097969900-if01'
creating link '/dev/serial/by-id/usb-ARM_DAPLink_CMSIS-DAP_0311000032254e4500518006aebb0014bbf1000097969900-if01' to '/dev/ttyACM0'
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/serial/by-id/usb-ARM_DAPLink_CMSIS-DAP_0311000032254e4500518006aebb0014bbf1000097969900-if01' to '../../ttyACM0'
found 'c166:0' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2fserial\x2fby-path\x2fplatform-xhci-hcd.0.auto-usb-0:1.5:1.1'
creating link '/dev/serial/by-path/platform-xhci-hcd.0.auto-usb-0:1.5:1.1' to '/dev/ttyACM0'
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/serial/by-path/platform-xhci-hcd.0.auto-usb-0:1.5:1.1' to '../../ttyACM0'
created db file '/run/udev/data/c166:0' for '/devices/soc/6a00000.ssusb/6a00000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.1/tty/ttyACM0'
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-path/platform-xhci-hcd.0.auto-usb-0:1.5:1.1 /dev/serial/by-id/usb-ARM_DAPLink_CMSIS-DAP_0311000032254e4500518006aebb0014bbf1000097969900-if01
DEVNAME=/dev/ttyACM0
DEVPATH=/devices/soc/6a00000.ssusb/6a00000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.1/tty/ttyACM0
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=tty-platform-xhci-hcd_0_auto-usb-0_1_5_1_1
ID_MODEL=DAPLink_CMSIS-DAP
ID_MODEL_ENC=DAPLink\x20CMSIS-DAP
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=LPC1768
ID_MODEL_ID=0204
ID_PATH=platform-xhci-hcd.0.auto-usb-0:1.5:1.1
ID_PATH_TAG=platform-xhci-hcd_0_auto-usb-0_1_5_1_1
ID_REVISION=1000
ID_SERIAL=ARM_DAPLink_CMSIS-DAP_0311000032254e4500518006aebb0014bbf1000097969900
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0311000032254e4500518006aebb0014bbf1000097969900
ID_TYPE=generic
ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Miscellaneous Device
ID_USB_DRIVER=cdc_acm
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:030000:020201:0a0000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
ID_USB_PROTOCOL_FROM_DATABASE=Interface Association
ID_VENDOR=ARM
ID_VENDOR_ENC=ARM
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=NXP
ID_VENDOR_ID=0d28
MAJOR=166
MINOR=0
SUBSYSTEM=tty
TAGS=:uaccess:seat:systemd:
USEC_INITIALIZED=138162670
run: 'uaccess'
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```